# Firebird error: Attempted update of read-only database

Tags: firebird

I am using firebird database version 2.0. When I try to update a row, I get an error message: Attempted update of read-only database.

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq359/ suggests I may query a blob field that uses a different character set than the connection character set.

I do query a blob field and when the blob field has a value then the updating causes the error. If there is no value in the blob then the updating is just fine.

I use IBConsole to open the firebird database and check the database metadata, I find the metadata says "Default character set NONE".

To fix the problem I firstly need to know what are the character sets used in my database.

So my questions are:

1. what is the character set being used for my database (Connection character set)
2. the data type of the blob field is MEMOBLOB, and MEMOBLOB is created as Create domain MEMOBLOB as blob sub_type TEXT segment size 80; So what is the character set use for the MEMOBLOB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not about queries or BLOBs.

Firebird databases have a number of modes, one of them is "read-only". In this mode no any change to database is allowed.

You can use `gfix` utility to change this database mode. You can also use corresponding menu in IBExpert and other development tools that use Firebird `Services API`

The very link you posted - http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq359/ - says that:

> It does not mean that the database file is read-only, but it (database) **contains a read-only mark**

- gfix -mode read_only /path/to/database.fdb
- gfix -mode read_write /path/to/database.fdb

See also https://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix-dbmode.html

See also https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.DatabaseProperties

---

Of tangential questions:

> character set being used for my database

According to your text, it is NONE.

To be exact, database does not use some charset. It is every textual column (char/varchar/blob sub_type text) that do. But usually developer does not bother with specifying individual per-column charsets, so they inherit that default one.

Read also: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-character

> metadata says "Default character set NONE"

This is as close to "database charset" as can be.

Granted, that is only *default* one and you could override it when creating your columns, but i do not think you did. So probably all your textual columns have charset "NONE".

That is rather dangerous setting, meaning all texts in such columns are stored as raw bytes dump, and hoping application would correctly guess how to convert bytes to letters and letters to bytes.

Read more: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-chartypes.html

Flame Robin seems not to show charset by default, but maybe in DDL section it would.
http://www.flamerobin.org/images/screenshots/0.6.0/gtk2/property_page.png

IBExpert does: https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/uploads/Doc/dmiles783.gif

> (Connection character set)

....is not "character set used by database", it is character set used by, well, connection your application (such as IBConsole or FlameRobin or IBExpert) makes to the database.
You have to set it in every application's connection properties. Easiest option would be UTF-8, but when you have NONE-charset columns it might fail...

For example in FR: http://www.flamerobin.org/images/screenshots/0.7.1/winxp/databaseinfo.png

You can use `monitoring tables` to query for charset id of your `CURRENT_CONNECTION`, see more at https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx05-monattach.html

Answer (score 1):

After I add transaction parameters for the relevant tables. It solves the problem.
The parameter value I added are isc_tpb_lock_write and isc_tpb_shared.

Thank you Arioch 'The.